# PDO retrieves two-dimensional array instead of one-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

In MySQL I have the following table:

```
|type_id | type_name     |
--------------------------
|1       | John Doe      |
|2       | Peter Griffin |
|3       | Max Wilcox    |
```

My PHP Code looks like this:

```
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare ( "SELECT $column FROM $table" );
    $stmt->execute ();

    return $stmt->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

This is the result of the `return` statement:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type_name] => John Doe
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type_name] => Peter Griffin
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type_name] => Max Wilcox
        )
)
```

Is there a way to get the following output in a direct way?

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Doe
    [1] => Peter Griffin
    [2] => Max Wilcox
)
```

At the moment I am converting a two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array, but this is quite inefficient. If I use PDO::FETCH_NUM the result looks quite similar but instead of "type_name" I always get "0". Maybe someone can help me to modify my PHP statement? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your PHP code in a function ? ref: `return $stmt->fetchAll ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );`

Comment: yes it is in a function.

Comment: @Peter what is name of function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO retrieves [**exactly what you ask it for.**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

To get a one-dimensional array you have to use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

```
return $dbh->query("SELECT $column FROM $table" )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Note that your query is **critically prone to SQL injection.** PDO shouldn't be used that way. Do not try to automate SQL. It's already perfectly automated. Use a literal query like `SELECT foo,bar  FROM baz WHERE id=1` instead. There is not that much writing you're probably afraid of, and there will be not that much use of this function in a *real world* code as you probably hope for.

OR

use a ready-made **query builder**, such as Doctrine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works now. I know that it is critically prone to SQL injection. Do you have an sugesstion how to improve it?